# Apache Permanent Redirect Removes Slash From Path

Tags: redirect, https, apache-2.4

I'm using Apache 2.4, and I set up two virtual directories.  One requires SSL, and the other one redirects to it.

If a user attempts to visit `https://www.derp.com/derp` without /derp existing, they correctly get a 404.  But when a user visits `http://www.derp.com/derp`, Apache incorrectly redirects the user to `https://www.derp.comderp`, removing the slash between the path and the domain name.

I have no idea what would be causing this.

The following is the setup of my Virtual Host.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin derp@derp.com
    ServerName www.derp.com
    ServerAlias derp.com
    DocumentRoot "C:\Users\derp\Documents\Web Projects\derp"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "C:\Apache24\certs\cert.cer"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:\Apache24\certs\key.key"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin derp@derp.com
    ServerName www.derp.com
    ServerAlias derp.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.derp.com/
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "C:\Users\derp\Documents\Web Projects\derp">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    SSLRequireSSL
</Directory>
```

Why would Apache be behaving this way?

Bonus Question: Should redirects be handled in my virtual host definition, or should it be handled in the .htaccess file in the web site's physical directory?

**Edit:**

I'm starting a Laravel project, and by default the public folder does contain a .htaccess file, so here's that guy:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Edit Two:**

I tried:

- adding a slash at the end of the DirectoryRoot path
- replacing the backslashes with forward slashes in the DirectoryRoot path
- replacing the backslashes with double backslashes in the DirectoryRoot path

I also removed the .htaccess file from the directory completely.

It redirects correctly when you go from `http://www.derp.com` to `https://www.derp.com`.  It's just when you specify a path and attempt https that it removes the slash between the domain and the path.

**Edit Three:**

I also attempted the following suggestion:

> ```
> Redirect permanent / https://www.derp.com/
>
> Try
>
> RedirectMatch permanent /(.*) https://www.derp.com/$1
>
> or
>
> RedirectMatch permanent (.*) https://www.derp.com/$1
> ```

... and instead of redirecting to https://www.derp.comderp, it instead does not redirect, attempts and gives a 404 for http://www.derp.com/derp, but using Apache's 404, instead of throwing a Not Found Exception, as Laravel does without configuration.

Comment: The config you provided isn't doing that, you probably have a `RewriteRule` elsewhere doing redirecting as well? Can you provide the contents of that `.htaccess`?

Comment: Thanks Shane.  I threw the contents of that file up there.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.htaccess` for Laravel looks off. It seems like just a simple `.htaccess` for SEF/SEO friendly URLs I assume. So instead of it being this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Try this instead:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't solve the issue either.  :(

Comment: You know - I just came back to read this.  Could you explain those changes a little more in depth?

Answer (score -1):

L4.1 redirects the trailing slash at .htaccess not in the foundation application class as it did previously

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes…
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Just comment it out